# geom_bspline across multiple plots combined into a single figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a `ggplot2` layer that includes multiple `geom_bspline()`, or something similar, to point to regions on different plots after combining them into a single figure. A feature in the data seen in one plot appears in another plot after a transformation. However, it may not be clear to a non-expert they are due to the same phenomenon. The plots are to be combined into a single figure using `ggarrange()`, `cowplot()`, `patchwork()` or something similar.

I can get by using `ggforce::geom_ellipse()` on each plot but it's not as clean. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, after asking the question and staring at the figure in question, it came to me that I simply need to add a geom_bspline() to the combined figure. Tried that earlier but didn't give enough thought to the coordinates on the new layer. The coordinates of the spline are given in the range of 0 to 1 for both the x and y values on this new layer. Simple and obvious.